# List of valid suid/sgid executables on Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, suid

Can anyone tell me where to find a list of valid suid/guid programs on Linux, ideally Ubuntu?

Note I can use find to get a list of suid/sgid programs on my machine, but I want to know if they are real valid programs; is there a list I can compare them against?

Comment: ask this in askubuntu.com

Comment: OK, just created an account at askubuntu and asked the question there.

Comment: My question was answered on askubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/546810/list-of-valid-suid-sgid-executables.

Comment: good. Mark your question as being answered then :)

Comment: I tried to but something marked it as trivial and converted it to a comment, I've been trying to edit it but having problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One answer (from Rmano [on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/546810/list-of-valid-suid-sgid-executables), ) is copied below:

One idea - but will need a bit of work in scripting --- be my guest ;-)

```
Find a suid/sgid file; let's call it scommand

Check from which package has been installed:

dpkg -S /full/path/to/scommand 

Compare its permission with the original deb package, by firstly downloading the package:

apt-get download package

Check if the command should have the suid set in the package with

dpkg -c package*deb | grep /full/path/to/scommand

cleanup, rinse, repeat.
```

Example:

[romano:~/tmp] % ls -l /bin/passwd
ls: cannot access /bin/passwd: No such file or directory
[romano:~/tmp] 2 % ls -l /usr/bin/passwd
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 47032 Feb 17  2014 /usr/bin/passwd
[romano:~/tmp] % dpkg -S /usr/bin/passwd
passwd: /usr/bin/passwd
[romano:~/tmp] % apt-get download passwd
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main passwd amd64 1:4.1.5.1-1ubuntu9 [755 kB]
Fetched 755 kB in 1s (487 kB/s)
[romano:~/tmp] % dpkg -c passwd*.deb| grep /usr/bin/passwd
-rwsr-xr-x root/root     47032 2014-02-17 03:42 ./usr/bin/passwd

Answer (score 0):

Try this little script I wrote that searches the entire online archive of Ubuntu (or Debian or anything else that uses apt and dpkg, really):

```
PKG=$(apt-cache search . | cut -f 1 -d ' ');
echo $PKG | xargs apt-get download;
F=(`find *.deb`); for i in ${F[@]};
do dpkg -c $i | cut -c 4- | grep ^s | cut -c 4- | cut -f 2 -d '.';
done | tee suid_root;
```

Note that this takes a *lot* of disk space and bandwidth and isn't very optimized.